# Insert desordenado en tabla temporal

Tags: sql, sql-server

Cuando hago el select solo me devuelve la consulta tal y como yo quiero.

```
Select Distinct NombreCliente,OELMDT,OEQLVA,CodigoCliente,TLLINO,TLTX60
From #Templino,#Tempcliente
Where (CodigoCliente=CONCAT(RTRIM(#Templino.OEQLVA),'0000'))OR(CodigoCliente = CONCAT(RTRIM(#Templino.OEQLVA),'ZZZZ'))
Order by CodigoCliente, TLLINO asc;
```

El problema es que cuando intento guardar dichos resultados en una tabla temporal, se pasa el orden no se por donde...

```
create table #Tempclientelino
(
    NombreCliente varchar(255), 
    OELMDT varchar(255),
    OEQLVA varchar(255),
    CodigoCliente varchar(255),
    TLLINO varchar(255),
    TLTX60 varchar(255) 
)

Insert Into #Tempclientelino
Select Distinct NombreCliente,OELMDT,OEQLVA,CodigoCliente,TLLINO,TLTX60
From #Templino,#Tempcliente
Where (CodigoCliente=CONCAT(RTRIM(#Templino.OEQLVA),'0000'))OR(CodigoCliente = CONCAT(RTRIM(#Templino.OEQLVA),'ZZZZ'))
Order by CodigoCliente, TLLINO asc;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SQL Server** no garantiza ningún orden a menos que usemos la clausula `ORDER BY`, no importa si el orden se lo damos al insertar, ni, si además logramos que físicamente los registros se inserten con dicho orden, no tenemos garantía que se respetará dicho orden al momento de hacer un `SELECT` a menos que usemos un `ORDER BY`. El asumir que el orden de inserción es el "orden natural" que usa un `SELECT` con tablas temporales puede deberse a un comportamiento en alguna de las versiones anteriores, no tengo claro cual, pero sí recuerdo serios problemas como el que comentas. La solución que encontramos ya que muchas veces en las temporales no guardamos los campos por los que queremos ordenar: usar siempre un campo Orden `INT IDENTITY`, insertar con el orden deseado y luego hacer un `ORDER BY Orden`

Answer (score 3):

Las tablas de sql server, de cualquier base de datos relacional en realidad, no tienen una ordenación asociada y es necesario especificar la clausula order by para obtener una ordenación determinada.